# Combining Small function with Right function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two formulas on a worksheet.

The One goes through AN:AW which is =--Right(Bx,1), and the other one goes through AY:BH which is {=SMALL(ABx:AWx,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10})}.

Is there a way I can combine these two formulas together to give me the same result? I don't want to use a Macro for this, if possible, only with a function. (Here lowercase "x" represents row number). Note: Small function requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this array formula:

```
=SMALL(--RIGHT(Bx:Kx,1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10})
```

(Reminder: to enter an array formula, 
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)